# php regex to find some parts of code in php code generally and insert before something

Tags: php, regex

I am again stuck in php regex part of my app :(
Actually I am searching a type of an universal regex which will search and replace by template

-Any string, which has before string A and ends with string B

-Take that string with the  starting string A and with starting string B
-insert it

so lets say I have a need to search in code all

```
$template = 'admin_list.tpl';
```

I could make

```
$start="$template = '"; $end="';";

$template= "????????????????????";
$ocur=preg_match_all($search_template,$file_get_contents,$matches);
```

so what to put instead of  ?????????????? so that generally the search of content inside some given A and B will be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question and you're just looking for a regex to match everything between two strings, you'd probably just us something like:

```
/FIRSTSTRING(.*?)SECONDSTRING/s
```

In PHP if you are assembling the regex, you may want to do:

```
$regex ="/".preg_quote($start)."(.*?)".preg_quote($end)."/s";
```

Comment: $regex I should pass then to prech_match_all or preg_replace, right?

Comment: thanks paul! your are my lovliest regexers :))))) Have a lovely nice day!